# com.android.dex.DevException : Multiple dex files define Error in Unity 2017.3.1f

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

so I finished my game in Unity but when I try to build it to Android I am getting this error :

[image]

When I googled, I didnt see many people faced this problem and they usually faced a problem in BuildClass but I think mine is different so any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Check your android plugin files (usually located in /Assets/Plugins/Android). This is usually caused by having different versions of the same android library in there. So make sure there is always only one file for each library.

Comment: I imported GoogleMobileAds and GooglePlayPlugin to import ads and Leaderboard feature in my game. Does it have anything to do with this ?

Comment: I would assume so. The Google play plugin for unity also comes with an automated dependency resolver. So you should also search for the dependencies file in your project and have a look at that.